# PHP Session Variable not showing prior to unset being called

Tags: php, session, echo, unset

Basically I have the following code which is currently working fine as expected:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['message']) )
    {
    echo '<p class="user_message">'.$_SESSION['message'].'</p>';

    //unset( $_SESSION['message'] );
    }
```

As you can see the unset()  has been commented out. What I want to do is unset the session message after it has echo'd out. However when I run this code without the comments, the session variable is not echo'd out at all?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks for responding, however this solution does not work and returns the same result as my original attempt. Here is the code which defines the session message:

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "";

// We know user email exists if the rows returned are more than 0
if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {

$_SESSION['message'] = $_SESSION['message'].'User with this email already         exists!<br />';

 }
// Validate email address  
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

$_SESSION['message'] = $_SESSION['message'].'Email address is invalid, please try again!<br />';

}
// Validate Referral code
if ( $refby != "" ) {
if ( (count_digit($refby) > 0 && count_digit($refby) < 6) || count_digit($refby) > 6 ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $_SESSION['message'].'Referral code is invalid!<br />';
} elseif ( !is_numeric($refby) ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $_SESSION['message'].'Referral code is invalid!<br />';
}
```

}

```
 // Validate password length
if ( count_digit($_POST['password']) < 6 ) {

$_SESSION['message'] = $_SESSION['message'].'Password invalid, must be more than 6 characters!<br />';
```

}

```
// Validate password confirmed
if ( $_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm_password'] ) {

$_SESSION['message'] = $_SESSION['message'].'Your passwords do not match!<br     />';
```

}

```
 if ( count_digit($num1)>2 || count_digit($num2)>2 || count_digit($num3)>2 ||       count_digit($num4)>2 || count_digit($num5)>2 ) {

$_SESSION['message'] = $_SESSION['message'].'Please select your lucky    numbers!<br />';
 }

if ( $_SESSION['message'] != "" ) {
header("location: #register_content");
```

however, I dont understand how the code works perfectly prior to unsetting the session variable? even though the contents are echo'd prior to the session variable being unset?

Many thanks

Comment: if you run only that code it wont show because nothing is setting a value to `$_SESSION['message']`

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['message'])` doesn't check if there are any values in the session, only if its set. It can be set and empty at the same time.

Comment: Can you provide more code please? What is leading up to this point? When/how are you setting the message session var?

Comment: can't give a right answer with only this code

Comment: More code added thanks, I can confirm that the message variable holds data, if I remove the unset() from the original code the script executes as it should. The only problem being the message variable remains set to hold errors.

Comment: replace `isset` with `empty` in your IF statement.

Comment: Hi Martin thanks for your reply. The display of the session variable is not the problem. The problem is I need to unset the session variable once it has been echo'd onto the page. Using unset straight after echo results in the message not being displayed

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone interested.

This occurs because the script continues to run, not really sure how it works but basically once the session variable is removed, the script can no longer refer to it.

Once the session variable is unset in the script, `exit(0);` is required. This resolves the problem and the session variable is unset, however the script still echo's out the contents of the session variable prior to it being unset.

Comment: Bingo. It's for this reason that I only use a custom `redirect` function that sets the location header and then kills the script - so that I never forget to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['message']) )
{
    $message = $_SESSION['message'];
    echo '<p class="user_message">'.$message.'</p>';
    unset( $_SESSION['message'] );
}
```

It will print the data as well as unset it later.

also remember to call `session_start()` at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, I tried to show user alert if $_SESSION['SuccessAlert'] is set, and after I show the message unset the value.

It didn't work.

My solution was to use cookies.

**In PHP :**

```
setcookie('SuccessAlert',"Your post was successfully save");
```

**In Javascript:**

In the javascript tag, check if the cookie exists, show the message and remove the cookie.